# Ant + concat + fileset: is the alphabetical order of the files preserved?

Tags: java, ant, filenames, concatenation

I have the following files:

```
C:/test/files/1f.txt, contains the string "file1"
C:/test/files/2f.txt, contains the string "file2"
C:/test/files/3f.txt, contains the string "file3"
```

If I use the following Ant task (Ant 1.6.5):

```xml
<concat destfile="C:/test/concat.txt">
    <fileset dir="C:/test/files">
        <include name="*.txt" />                      
    </fileset>
</concat>
```

Will the content of `concat.txt` always be `file1file2file3`, or is it possible that the alphabetical order of the files isn't preserved, and thus have `file2file1file3` for example? And that on Windows, Linux and Solaris operating systems?

I had few tries on Windows, and it seems that yes, the order is preserved, but I need to be sure about it. If not, could you provide an counterexample, where the alphabetical order isn't preserved?

PS: nesting a `<sort>` within the `<concat>` isn't allowed in Ant 1.6.5, but only in Ant 1.7+.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you can rely on the order. But I cannot provide a counterexample.

Maybe you can use a `<sort>` element to force a specified order:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#sort

It should be something like that:

```
<concat destfile="C:/test/concat.txt">
    <sort>
        <fileset dir="C:/test/files">
            <include name="*.txt" />                      
        </fileset>
        <name/>
    </sort>
</concat>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that, Ant 1.6.5 doesn't allow a `<sort>` within a `<concat>`, but only Ant 7+ (and I can't migrate to Ant 7+).